# Deno logger FileHandler not writing to file

Tags: typescript, logging, deno

I'm trying to setup some loggers for an app. I have a `console` handler which write every log to the console. And a `app` handler which should write any log to some file.

The logs are writen correctly to the console, but none of the files are writen, and I can't get why.

```js
import { setup as loggerSetup, getLogger } from "https://deno.land/std/log/mod.ts";
import {
  ConsoleHandler,
  FileHandler,
} from "https://deno.land/std/log/handlers.ts";
import { ensureDir } from "https://deno.land/std/fs/ensure_dir.ts";

const logDir = Deno.env.get("LOG_DIR") || "./logs";

await ensureDir(logDir);

const consoleLoggerHandler = new ConsoleHandler("DEBUG");
const applicationLoggerHandler = new FileHandler("DEBUG", {
  filename: logDir + "/application.log",
  formatter: "{msg}",
});
const errorLoggerHandler = new FileHandler("WARNING", {
  filename: logDir + "/errors.log",
});

await loggerSetup({
  handlers: {
    console: consoleLoggerHandler,
    app: applicationLoggerHandler,
    errors: errorLoggerHandler,
  },
  loggers: {
    default: {
      level: "DEBUG",
      handlers: ["console", "app"],
    },
    app: {
      level: "INFO",
      handlers: ["app"],
    },
    error: {
      level: "WARNING",
      handlers: ["errors"],
    },
  },
});

export const logger = getLogger();
export const appLogger = getLogger("app");
export const errorLogger = getLogger("error");
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, nothing at all

Comment: Can you try this:errorLogger.warning('sample warning');

Comment: I am also facing the same error. My console log is working properly but file is not. As suggested in the document filehandle flush is called every 30 seconds, but even after 30 seconds, my log file is not updaing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to call `applicationLoggerHandler.flush()` method in order to write on file.